# showing import error in python while i have the packages in sys.path

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, import

i have packages on the sys.path but it shows import error . but if i try to import the same packages on level upper in directory structure it works.

```
(flask) [ tests ] $ python3
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2019, 09:21:52) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20191008] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/rohit/flask/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/rohit/flask/src/flaskr', '/home/rohit/flask/src/mycode']
>>> import mycode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mycode'
>>> import flaskr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flaskr'
>>> exit()


(flask) [ tests ] $ cd ..
(flask) [ src ] $ python3
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2019, 09:21:52) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20191008] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/rohit/flask/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/rohit/flask/src/flaskr', '/home/rohit/flask/src/mycode']
>>> import mycode
>>> import flaskr
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your test showed: If the packages you want to import are `/home/rohit/flask/src/flaskr` and `/home/rohit/flask/src/mycode`, you need to add `/home/rohit/flask/src` to your path. Your second try works because you are in this folder.

You can further test it with :

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/rohit/flask/src')
# with relative import for a test module in test subdirectory:
# sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

import mycode
import flaskr
```

Source : https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/modules.html#packages  : `When importing the package, Python searches through the directories on sys.path looking for the package subdirectory.`